# How handle concurrent requests with custom priority in Python?

Tags: python, concurrency, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

1. I have a high QPS of requests.
2. I can only handle **ONE request at a time**. So the pending request needs to be stored in a local Array/Queue.
3. When there is contention, I do not want FCFS (first-come-first-serve). Instead I want to process the request based own some custom logic.

Pseudocode like this

```py
def webApiHandler(request):
 future = submit(request)
 response = wait(future) # Wait time is depending on its priority
 return response
```

What primitives I can use to implement this? Event loop? Asyncio? Threads?

------------edit------------

**This is synchronous API call, everything should be handled locally and response ASAP once the computation is done. I do not plan to use job queue like celery.**

Answer (score 0):

With your requirements (but why do you not want concurrency ?) what you might want to use is literraly a priority queue, which is a queue with ... priority : info of implementation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) , and you can use it in python with the `queue` module [(doc here)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.PriorityQueue)

it is sorted by priority, so higher priority are at the end of the queue.

Your implementation will then decide how to value the request and set the priority on this particular request. But two identic priority will be treated as in a queue.

Then, you write a consumer in another thread that will pop the first (or last depending on what you consider top priority) item in the queue.

What you might want to look at, and enable concurrency and extra features is [celery](https://github.com/celery/celery), which is a distributed task queue framework. (it allows for queue, priority, and also can be run with a any number of worker (any=1 in your case, but are you really into non-concurrency for high number of request ?).

Comment: Clarified my requirements a bit, I DO want concurrency and I DO NOT want because it has to be synchronous API call.

Comment: You mean multiple client are waiting for response but the requests are treated in parallel ? You don't usually do that (using a task queue you asynchronously check if it is done), but you can wait for a task to end in celery.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
import asyncio
import threading
from typing import Dict

# Local queue for pending compute (watchout, may need to replace dict for thread-safe ⚠️) 
pending_computes: Dict[int, list[threading.Event]] = {}

# The queue manager to pick a pending compute
async def poll_next():
  # 1. A computed example after updating model priority
  priorities = [2, 1, 3] # TODO: handle the empty array.

  # 2. Find the next compute event reference
  next = pending_computes.get(priorities[0]) # TODO: handle empty dict.

  # 3. Kick off the next compute
  next.set()

# The FastAPI async handler
async def cloud_compute_api(model_id: int, intput: bytes):
  # 1. Enqueue current compute as an event.
  compute_event = threading.Event()
  pending_computes.get(model_id, []).append(compute_event)

  # 2. Poll the next pending compute based on.
  asyncio.create_task(poll_next) 

  # 3. Wait until its own compute is set to GO. Wait up to 10 seconds.
  compute_event.wait(10)

  # 4. compute starts 
  res = compute(model_id, intput)
  asyncio.create_task(poll_next) # Poll next pending compute, if any

  return res
```